# Webpack to ignore huge npm module

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, webpack

I'm using webpack and typescript.

Im my `app.ts` I have something like this:

```
import * as math from "mathjs";

// some code using mathjs
math.multiply(math.complex(1,2), math.complex(3,4));
```

since I'm using mathjs, my webpack bundle is 1.8MB and takes ~30seconds to compile.

Is there any way to tell webpack that mathjs will never ever be modified, it can be compiled only once, and from that point, webpack should not care about it?

(I've tried all webpack plugins and settings, but found no solution)

Comment: Anything you use will need to be bundled. What you can do is make use of tree-shaking and only import the utilities you need, ie `import { multiple, complex } from "mathjs"`

Comment: @Phil in the js output of TS it will be a simple require('mathjs') :(